# Pandas DataFrame from list/dict/list

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data in this form:

```
a = [{'table': 'a', 'field':['apple', 'pear']}, 
     {'table': 'b', 'field':['grape', 'berry']}]
```

I want to create a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    field table
0   apple     a
1   pear      a
2   grape     b
3   berry     b
```

When I try this:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(a)
```

I get this:

```
            field table
0   [apple, pear]     a
1  [grape, berry]     b
```

I'm using a loop to restructure my original data, but I think there must be a more straightforward and simpler methid.

Comment: How do you infer `berry c`? Shouldn't it be `b`.

Comment: @umutto is correct - I will edit question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to concatenate a series of dataframes, one for each dictionary in `a`.

```
>>> pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'table': d['table'],  # Per @piRSquared for simplification.
                             'field': d['field']})
               for d in a]).reset_index(drop=True)
   field table
0  apple     a
1   pear     a
2  grape     b
3  berry     b
```

Comment: I love that!  Smart!

Comment: This is the solution I used. Perfect.

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1**
comprehension

```
pd.DataFrame([{'table': d['table'], 'field': f} for d in a for f in d['field']])

   field table
0  apple     a
1   pear     a
2  grape     b
3  berry     b
```

---

**Option 2**
reconstruct

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
pd.DataFrame(dict(
    table=d1.table.repeat(d1.field.str.len()),
    field=np.concatenate(d1.field)
)).reset_index(drop=True)

   field table
0  apple     a
1   pear     a
2  grape     b
3  berry     b
```

---

**Option 3**
Rubik's Cube

```
pd.DataFrame(a).set_index('table').field.apply(pd.Series) \
    .stack().reset_index('table', name='field').reset_index(drop=True)

  table  field
0     a  apple
1     a   pear
2     b  grape
3     b  berry
```

Comment: I prefer option 1.  Given that `table` is a scalar, I can just take its value.

Comment: Option 3 is an interesting approach, although I wouldn't want to review it six months down the line and ask WTF did I write back then... (-;

Comment: Amen to that.  But hey!  It's one line and that has to count for something.  I heard one line makes things faster and cotton candy taste like unicorns.

Comment: I like option 3 :)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try using `pd.wide_to_long` ,I do want to use `lreshape`, but it is undocumented and personally not recommended ...T _ T

```
a = [{'table': 'a', 'field':['apple', 'pear']},
     {'table': 'b', 'field':['grape', 'berry']}]
df=pd.DataFrame.from_records(a)
```

---

```
df[['Feild1','Feild2']]=df.field.apply(pd.Series)
pd.wide_to_long(df,['Feild'],'table','lol').reset_index().drop('lol',axis=1).sort_values('table')

Out[74]: 
  table  Feild
0     a  apple
2     a   pear
1     b  grape
3     b  berry
```